# unable to log data into database table using node js

Tags: javascript

```
DatabaseConnection.prototype.add_user_transaction =function(tournamenId,userId, callback ){

     var dbConn = this;

     var insertObject = {
        //data
        };
     var ticketModel = dbConn.rummyConnection.model('tournament_user_transactions');
     var transactionPromise = ticketModel.update(insertObject ,{where: {tournament_id: tournamenId, user_Id: userId}}).then(function(result) {
        callback({status:"SUCCESS", result: result});
     }).catch(function(err){

        debug(err.stack);
        var error = new Error('Error ');
        callback({status:"ERROR", error:error});
     });
};



// On debug result is[0], record is not inserting into table.
```

Comment: What database are you using? What driver for this database are you using for node?

Comment: you are invoking `update`. seems like this might not do anything if there's nothing in the database to update. typically database systems do a sort of `update where` kind of thing. Maybe what you want is an `upsert` functionality?